# How can I make a variable of the same type as another using templates?

Tags: c++, templates, variables

I'd like to create a variable which matches the type of another variable by way of a template such that if the other variable ever changes type to match, the one derived from it via a template also changes its type.

How can I do this with templates in C++?

The purpose is to ensure that when I read from disk into a temporary variable that the number of bytes read from disk exactly matches the actual variable.  In this case, I am going to ignore the value so don't want to read to the actual variable, but need to make sure I read the right number of bytes before moving on to keep things in sync.

Comment: The problem, as you stated it, is not solvable neither with nor without templates in the current version of C++. In some cases one can come up with a workaround, but we need more context for that.

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you are not using a `typedef` and use that for both variables?

Comment: Georg Fritzsche> You should make that an answer.

Comment: Well a typedef doesn't guarantee they don't end up diverging.  What if the original variable is edited away from the typedef?

Comment: so how could *anything* possibly offer this guarantee? One of the variables can *always* be edited to have another type. That is just a ridiculous argument. You want a language feature that protects against source code modifications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have decltype available in your compiler, you can write a template function to accomplish this.  It's kind of ugly but it will get the job done.

```
template<typename T>
T read_alike(int fd, T const &unusedVar)
{
    T realVar;
    if (::read(fd, &realVar, sizeof(realVar)) != sizeof(realVar)
        throw std::runtime_error("read failed or incomplete");
    return realVar;
}
```

You'd call it like:

```
MyClass myObj;

MyClass newObj = read_alike(fd, myobj);
```

Answer (score 2):

With the current standard, I don't think you can do this without some really hardcore metaprogramming tricks. The solution wouldn't be ideal. edit> In fact I think it's not possible.

The next standard will provide decltype operator that let you get the type of a variable or expression :

```
A a;
decltype(a) b; // b is of type A
```

If you use a recent compiler, like MSVC10 or Gcc4.5, this feature is already available (check the auto keyword too).